# Looking for R Studi function/code to cross-reference variables

Tags: r

I would appreciate if anyone could advise me on how to establish a relationship between 2 variables. It might be super easy, but I'm new to R. I cannot attach photos of what my dataset (X2015_11_metropolitan_stop_and_search) looks like, but here's a dput on the two variables that I'm interested in:

```
dput(X2015_11_metropolitan_stop_and_search$Object of search)
c("Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Fireworks", "Controlled drugs", "Stolen goods", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", "Fireworks", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Evidence of offences under the Act", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Offensive weapons", "Stolen goods", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Offensive weapons", "Offensive weapons", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs", "Controlled drugs" )
```

```
dput(X2015_11_metropolitan_stop_and_search$Outcome)
c("Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", "Suspect arrested", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Offender given drugs possession warning", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Offender given drugs possession warning", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Suspect arrested", "Suspect arrested", "Offender given drugs possession warning", 
"Suspect arrested", "Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Suspect arrested", "Suspect arrested", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Suspect arrested", "Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Suspect arrested", "Suspect arrested", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Nothing found - no further action", 
"Nothing found - no further action", "Offender given drugs possession warning", 
"Suspect arrested", "Offender given penalty notice", "Nothing found - no further action")
```

There is a small number of possible values for the variables 'Object of search' and 'Outcome'. I'd like to be able to see the 'Object of search' value for those individual incidents where the 'Outcome' value was 'Suspect arrested'. Is that possible?

In case I need to include more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
X2015_11_metropolitan_stop_and_search$Object of search[X2015_11_metropolitan_stop_and_search$Outcome == "Suspect arrested"]
```

Which would return all the values of 'Object of search' that have the outcome "suspect arrested". A generic version of this would be:

```
data$column1[data$column2 == "dataValue"]
```

Also check out the which() function to return the index number of data that fit the parameters you specify in the function.